# How To Force Redirect To A Certain Directory via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am on a server running WordPress. WP is installed in the Document Root and the .htaccess file below is controlling every request.

What I need to do is have a certain directory off the Document Root, let's call it "bypass", resolve on its own and not run through WordPress.

Is that possible? What might the .htaccess directive(s) look like to make that happen?

Thanks for helping me solve this need.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ems /ems/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: If you have a directory in the Document Root, and don't have any page/post in WordPress with the same name, then you don't need any .htaccess rule.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Virendra -- it didn't seem to work but I'll go back and try it again.

Comment: make sure you don't have any page or post by the same permalink, only then it would work without any .htaccess rule. I just cross checked it on a site that I had similar situation and it works perfectly fine without any .htaccess rules.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Virendra. I'll post back tomorrow morning after I try it again. That will be in about 10 hours from now.

Comment: It worked. Not exactly sure what I had done wrong, but thanks @Virendra

Comment: That's gr8. I'll move my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a directory in the Document Root, and don't have any page/post in WordPress with the same name, then you don't need any .htaccess rule.

Make sure you don't have any page or post by the same permalink, only then it would work without any .htaccess rule.